Difference between __add__() and add() inside the class definition in Python
I am learning OOP in Python and I came across the situation where I want to add two objects. I have seen people using the format below:
class GFG: 

    def __init__(self, val): 
        self.val = val 
          
    def __add__(self, val2): 
        return GFG(self.val + val2.val) 

obj1 = GFG("Geeks") 
obj2 = GFG("ForGeeks") 
obj3 = obj1 + obj2 
print(obj3.val)

But I am wondering if we could use def add() in the place of def __add__(). If yes or no, could you please explain in detail why it works or not.
I tried to replace def __add__() with def add() but I got error which is something like this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Solution.py", line 11, in <module>
 obj3 = obj1 + obj2 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'GFG' and 'GFG'


Python automatically converts the + operator into a call to the __add__() method. There's nothing that knows about your add() method automatically, so it doesn't work in that case.

You can write obj1.add(obj2) to use your method name, but it won't be used for the + operator.

What is your idea about how this works that made you think it would work with some other method name?

1. __ add__( ) :
This is a special method in Python, also known as a "magic method", its primary purpose is to define how the addition operator (+) behaves when used with objects of your class. It gets called automatically whenever you use + between two objects of the same class. The definition requires two parameters: self (referring to the left operand object) and other(referring to the right operand object). The method should return a new object that represents the result of adding the two original objects.
2. add( ) :
This is a regular method defined like any other method within your class. It doesn't have a special role in the language and isn't inherently linked to the addition operation. You can use it for various purposes, such as performing calculation, updating data, or interacting with other objects.
Key Differences and Why You Get an Error:
__ add__( ) is specific to object addition, while add( ) can serve any purpose.
__ add__( ) gets called automatically by the + operator, whereas add( ) needs to be explicity called as a method.
Replacing __ add__( ) with add( ) leads to a TypeError when using + with your objects. Python doesn't know how to add objects of the GFG class using + because you haven't defined that behavior.
Example:
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def add_age(self, years):
    self.age += years

person1 = Person("John", 30)
person1.add_age(5)
print(person1.age)  # 35

